# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio for Windows XP

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp, ssms

I already searched for it and tried to install the 2012 version on my Windows XP (got an error that I have to upgrade to min. Win Vista) but is there still a hack or something like that to install it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Read the minimum requirements.
[minimum requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms143506.aspx)

but you can do a virtual machine "win7" and run SSMS on it.