# Using SQL Server 2012 with SSMS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SSMS 2008 on an XP machine, trying to access a SQL Server 2012 database and get error messages indicating index out of bounds of array. What do I need to do to fix?

Comment: You need to upgrade your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** (thanks [@bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) ) : You can't install SSMS 2012 on Windows XP. See here: [SQL Server 2012 Management Studio for Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15520853/325521)

**Cause**

> The server you are connecting to is using SQL Server 2012. The error
>   is a result of incompatibilities with previous versions of SQL Server
>   Management Studio i.e. 2005, 2008, & 2008 R2.

**Resolution**

> You will need to download SQL Server 2012 Management Studio to make
>   changes to your database. You can download it from the MSSQL Express
>   2012 website.

Source of Answer: [You Receive Errors When Connecting to MSSQL 2012 Using MSSQL 2008 or 2008 R2 Management Studio.](http://support.powerdnn.com/kb/a1781/you-receive-errors-when-connecting-to-mssql-2012-using)